# Sql Server database mirroring and ASP.Net applications

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

With SQL Server database mirroring, do we need to take care of something in our ASP.Net applications or does it only require a connection string change in web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the configuration of the mirroring; as to whether you have automatic failover setup, etc.

If you have failover enabled, the connection string will stay the same as it should just point to the virtual IP of the failover using DNS or directly.

If not, you may have to change it to whichever host is active at that point.

As far as the application is concerned, it just needs to know where it gets it's data from and this is the connection string from web.config.